# Can I grade assignments "logged as student" with Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-classroom

I have an app using Google Classroom API. When connected as the teacher I can create course works and assignments. When connected as a student I can list my assignments and I can turn in a specific assignment.

I am using the REST API:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest

When (logged as student) I turn in an assignment but I would like to include a draft grade.

I know if I were logged as the teacher I could set the grade, but what I want is the app calculating the draft grade based on some specific built-in logic, so that the teacher does not have to do it on their own for each student.

According to the documentation, both "draftGrade" and "assignedGrade" can only be updated by the teacher.
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#StudentSubmission

Any ideas about how to automate setting grades for submissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible: you cannot update the draftGrade with student privileges.

What you can do:

1. From the "student" session you save a draft grade in the application DB, associated to the Submission ID.
2. From the "teacher" session, and hence "teacher" permissions, you get the grade from the application DB and I call the Path query to set the draftGrade.

Some code (Swift, using GoogleAPIClientForREST) for step 2:

```
    func executeQuery_GradeSubmission(studentSubmission: GTLRClassroom_StudentSubmission) -> GTLRServiceTicket? {
        guard let courseID = self.myClassroom?.courseID,
              let courseWorkID = self.selectedCourseWorkID else { return nil }

        if let grade = self.gradesForSelectedWorkID?[studentSubmission.identifier!] {
            studentSubmission.draftGrade = NSNumber(floatLiteral: Double(grade))
        }
        
        let query = GTLRClassroomQuery_CoursesCourseWorkStudentSubmissionsPatch.query(withObject: studentSubmission,
                                                                                      courseId: courseID,
                                                                                      courseWorkId: courseWorkID,
                                                                                      identifier: studentSubmission.identifier!)
        query.updateMask = "draftGrade"
        return self.myClassroom?.service.executeQuery(query,
                                                      delegate: self,
                                                      didFinish: #selector(displayGradeSubmissionResult(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
    }
    
    @objc func displayGradeSubmissionResult(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket, finishedWithObject: GTLRObject, error: Any?){
        let classroomSubmissionResponse = finishedWithObject as? GTLRClassroom_StudentSubmission
        
        if let classroomError = error as? NSError {
            print("displayGradeSubmissionResult. ERROR: \(classroomError.description)")
            // TODO: inform something went wrong
        } else {
            if let submissionItems = self.classroomSubmissionsResponse?.studentSubmissions {
                for submissionItem in submissionItems {
                    if submissionItem.identifier == classroomSubmissionResponse?.identifier {
                        submissionItem.draftGrade = classroomSubmissionResponse?.draftGrade
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```